# Compare selected value from dropdown

Tags: c#

I have this code on a timer function:

```
if(Status_Dropdown.Text== "Completed")
{              
     Lock_Fields();            
}
```

Also I tried this:

```
if (Status_Dropdown.SelectedIndex== 2)
{              
     Lock_Fields();            
}
```

But function work but when I put the mouse on hover, I want to perform the action after the user click on it.

Comment: What type is Status_Dropdown?

Comment: To confirm, you want to run the function after they click on it?

Comment: Yes, The dropdown have three options last option is completed, when the user click on it  I want to perform the action, currently what I have perform the action on mouse hover

Comment: Could you tie it to the SelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: Not sure because, I put it on a timer function because it can come from the dropdownlist but also can be returned from another form